# How could I simplify this algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How could I simplify $\frac{cos^{-1}}{sin^{-1}}$?

On desmos.com, I plotted the graph $\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)}{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\ = 1$, which looked like a quarter of an ellipse.

I tried to simplify this to $\tan\left(\frac{2y}{3x}\right)=1$, but I ended up getting a very weird and dynamic graph.

I also tried $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y}{3x}\right)=1$, however, it was a line this time.

What should I plot instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equate the numerator and denominator to each other and then take the sine. Note that the inverse cosine is so defined that its sine is nonnegative. Thus

$\arcsin(y/3)=\arccos(x/2)$

$\sin[\arcsin(y/3)]=\sin[\arccos(x/2)]$

$y/3=\sqrt{1-(x/2)^2}$

And then we clear radicals and recognize a standard form:

$(y/3)^2+(x/2)^2=1$

And so, your curve actually lies on an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\tan \dfrac{2 y}{3 x} = 1 \iff y = \dfrac{3}{2} \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4} + k \pi\right) x$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
   It a family of line passing by the origin.
2. $\tan^{-1} \dfrac{2 y}{3 x} = 1 \iff y = \dfrac{3}{2} x \tan 1$.
   It the a line passing by the origin.